# How to check the Free Space that Container left when upload files to Blob Storage Container in JAVA?

Tags: java, azure, azure-blob-storage

As mentioned above, I need to upload large volume of files to bob storage container using a JAVA program.

As my understanding, each container in Blob Storage has 50,000 size limit.

So my question is, how can I check the available size of container when I perform upload? If it is full during the upload, I can switch to another container and continue upload. Does anyone know how to check the available space of container using JAVA?

Comment: `As my understanding, each container in Blob Storage has 50,000 size limit.` - This is not correct. Please see this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/azure-subscription-service-limits#azure-blob-storage-limits.

Comment: 4000 MiB X 50,000 blocks, so 50,000 not correct?

Comment: Total size of a single blob is 190.7 TiB (4000 MiB X 50,000 blocks). Will you be uploading a file bigger than that?

Comment: Err, I not understand with it. It said 4000Mib x 50, 000 blocks. Which mean if my file size is small, then I can store over 50,000 blocks?

Comment: No, maximum blocks a block blob can have is 50,000 where each block can be maximum 4000Mib. You would want to split a blob into blocks if your blob size is large. For smaller sized blobs, you don't even have to split it in blocks.

Comment: So as you said, what is the total amount of files I can store in each container if all my files is around 4mb? Sorry I know my question might quite stupid but I really confused about this

Comment: No worries :). You're not alone. So essentially there's no size limit per container. There's a size limit per storage account which is 5 PiB (which is 5 x 1073741824 MB). Since your blob size is 4MB, you can probably store 1342177280 blobs (5 x 1073741824 / 4MB) in a storage account.

Comment: Oh I see!! Thanks for your explanation. Really appreciate it. Thank you.

Comment: @GauravMantri Could you please post your answers as a solution?